# error installing xmpp python lib in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

how to install xmpp python lib in ubuntu?

i downloaded this lib file
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-xmpp/python-xmpp_0.2-rc3.orig.tar.gz

when i say make install its giving me error

ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/DATA/ubuntu/xmpppy-0.2-rc3$ make install

## Add here commands to install the package into debian/python-xmpp

[ -d /xmpp ] || mkdir /xmpp
mkdir: cannot create directory `/xmpp': Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1

please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's a python package which uses [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to install, so make sure you have setuptools installed (`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`). Next, extract your xmpp package somewhere, and run setup tools like this:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

That should to the trick.

Comment: huh.. i am using live version of ubuntu.. will it work.. I have booted the system using pen drive

Comment: Why not? Pen drives are not read-only like live CDs, which by the way nowadays can mount virtual file systems in your memory too (I think).

Comment: ok i tried ur  command and again tried installing python dns package this time . still same kind of error. :(ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/DATA/ubuntu/dns/dnspython-1.6.0$ python setup.py installrunning install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dns
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dns': Permission denied

Comment: Well, I don't think you will be able to install the package unless you have write permissions to `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` so you should solve that first.

Comment: i tried changing file permission of /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ chmod 777 python2. .. .. . .giving me error (chmod: changing permissions of `python2.6': Operation not permitted)

Comment: The directory seems to be read-only, maybe your ubuntu live mounted it that way? Dump the contents of fstab and mtab somewhere and show us, and add `ubuntu` to the tags of this question, and perhaps rephrase it. You might also want to post it to serverfault or the ubuntu forums, but it shouldn't be very complicated. Other than that, this is not a python nor setuptools-related question ;)

Comment: i have touched linux after 4+ years.. and i right now dunno anything about linux than some very basic commands. i didnt get what this mean  " Dump the contents of fstab and mtab somewhere and show us, and add ubuntu to the tags of this question, and perhaps rephrase it." new to python too :D and actually i have tried putting ubuntu tag for this question.but it doesnt give ubuntu tag option